# What is the benefit of employing a bitizen in their dream job?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

What is the benefit of employing a bitizen in their *dream job* and when should I employ this bitizen over a not-dream-job bitizen with a higher rating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place a bitizen in their dream job, then the position that they are in stocks twice as many products, and you get a free chip.  If you look at the number of products stocked on a floor for a bitizen who has their dream job, it will show a "x2" display to denote this.

Since the benefit of having a highly-skilled worker is just a 1% discount per skill level, it is always a good idea to put a bitizen in their dream job.